# I failed to install my laravel 8 app on live server with PHP 7.3

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I tried to upload my laravel 8 app on remote server with ubuntu 18
and PHP 7.3.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

but I got error running composer :

```
 composer install
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires unicodeveloper/laravel-emoji 1.0.* -> satisfiable by unicodeveloper/laravel-emoji[1.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.26.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - unicodeveloper/laravel-emoji 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v8.26.1, 8.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.26.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.26.1, 8.x-dev].
```

On my local server (also ubuntu 18 ) I have PHP 7.4.13

In composer.json of my project :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial": "^5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "inacho/php-credit-card-validator": "^1.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/fortify": "^1.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.26.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
        "pragmarx/countries-laravel": "^0.7.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.41",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.10",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.6",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.18",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.4",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.15",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-emoji": "1.0.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.15"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^0.0.5",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan cache:clear"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@php artisan cache:clear"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it issue of PHP 7.3/PHP 7.4 difference and how it can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have some packages that will not run on Laravel 8..(unicodeveloper/laravel-emoji)

Comment: side note: don't run composer as root or superuser, thats not a safe way of using composer. You should also include the composer.lock file when you deploy a project. That way the versions will be the same as your dev env.

Comment: on Laravel 8 ? But I installed it locally in Laravel 8 app

Comment: Its a laravel 5 package, i just checked. You can install it by overruling the requirements, but that is not recomended. It is possible that the laravel version you have local is lower, so you did not have the problem (thats why you need to include your composer.lock file)

Comment: I got it. Any similar package for laravel 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this package instead:
https://github.com/spatie/emoji
It requires php ^7.2|^8.0 so should work on both your environments.

Comment: I installed this pluging and tryinmg examples {!! \Spatie\Emoji\Emoji::grinningFace() !!} - is rendered ok, but 
\{!! \Spatie\Emoji\Emoji::countryFlag('be') !!} showsn 2 chars “”.
Is it dependable from some other packages? I creared cache.

Comment: Composer is resolving all dependencies, you should already have everything what is needed for this package. I just installed the spatie/emoji on a fresh Laravel 8 and in my case, both `{{ \Spatie\Emoji\Emoji::countryFlag('be') }}` and `{!! \Spatie\Emoji\Emoji::countryFlag('be') !!}` expressions are only rendering one flag.

Comment: I tried a new app and also have “”.instead of country image. I used kubuntu 18. Which OS do you have? Or maybe I do not have  some fonts installed ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Not sure what you mean by "have “”.instead of country image.". In your comment I see the country flag, so probably the character outputted by the package is correct. If you see the replacement character instead of the flag, it's possible that system is unable to render it. I would: 1. check if your website is in UTF-8. 2. Try installing fonts-noto-color-emoji: `sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji` - it's not in other Ubuntu flavors if I remember good.

Comment: In resources/views/admin/layouts/app.blade.php I have 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

are there some other ways to check if I have UTF-8. I use only english text in the pages and db.
2) I installed fonts-noto-color-emoji and restarted apache : flags are not visible.
3) How I see it : https://prnt.sc/yp5b9o
4)

Comment: Wow, afder I restarted  OS I see how new fonts-noto-color-emoji are  applied and I see all flags. But if this fonts-noto-color-emoji plugin must be installed on my server or on OS of any client who opened my page ?

Comment: I believe it's client dependent. Most of the browsers should be able to render them correctly on modern OS. You can take a look at http://caniemoji.com/ to check which browsers on which OS supports emoji.